# Unit Test React-Redux Connected Components?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, react-redux

I am using Mocha, Chai, Nock, Sinon, Webpack for Unit tests.

I used the following link to test my actions, reducers 
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html

I was able to test dumb components from other react articles. Currently I am trying to test my smart component and i get errors.

my react-redux component (SmartComponent.js)

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import * as componentActions from '../actions/componentActions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

export class SmartComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.updateText = this.updateText.bind(this)
  }

  updateText(event){
    this.props.actions.updateText(event.target.value)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
       <input type='text' onChange={this.action1} placeholder='type something' 
       />
       <span>{this.props.inputText}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const inputText = state.inputText
  return{
    inputText
  } 
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(componentActions, dispatch)
  }
}

const SmartComponentContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SmartComponent)


module.exports = SmartComponentContainer
```

this is my unit test file

```
import setupDom from '../setup'
import chai from 'chai'
import jsxChai from 'jsx-chai'
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {findAllWithType, findWithType, findWithClass} from 'react-shallow-testutils'
import SmartComponentContainer,{SmartComponent} from "../containers/SmartComponent"

chai.use(jsxChai)
let expect = chai.expect



/**
 * Mock out the top level Redux store with all the required
 * methods and have it return the provided state by default.
 * @param {Object} state State to populate in store
 * @return {Object} Mock store
 */
function createMockStore(state) {
  return {
    subscribe: () => {},
    dispatch: () => {},
    getState: () => {
      return {...state};
    }
  };
}



function setup() {
  const storeState={
   inputText : ''
  }
  let renderer = TestUtils.createRenderer()
  renderer.render(<SmartComponentContainer store={createMockStore(storeState)}  />)
  let output = renderer.getRenderOutput()

  return {
    output,
    renderer
  }
}

function setUpComponent(){

const props ={}
 let renderer = TestUtils.createRenderer()
  renderer.render(<SmartComponent {...props} />)
  let output = renderer.getRenderOutput()

  return {
    output,
    renderer
  }

}

describe('test smart component container',()=>{

  it('test input value change',()=>{
    const {output,renderer} = setup()
    console.log(output)

   // when i do the console.log output here , i am getting my actions and state variable but i do not get the html inside render method 
  })

  it('test component',()=>{
    const {output,renderer} = setUpComponent()
    console.log(output)
  })


})
```

The first test is successful and i prints the output with actions and state variables but not able to get render html printed.

The second test throws an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'propTypes' of undefined" . I want access to html and have ability test like with normal component

```
expect(output.props.children[0].type).to.equal('input')
```

Comment: You may want to check my reply [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131312/how-to-unit-test-react-redux-connected-components)

Comment: mispost....................................

Comment: It looks like you're using ES6 module "export" to export your unconnected component, and CommonJS "module.exports" to export your connected component. It's a bad idea to mix the two, and may be causing issues with your babel compiling. Try using "export default" instead of "module.exports" and see if that helps.