# Test connected component in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs

I am trying test my connected component of my React/Redux app and I wrote some test case which actually throws the error:

```
App component › shows account info and debits and credits`

Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(AccountInfo)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(AccountInfo)".
```

The test case which trow an error `app.test.js` is below. And my problem is that I don't understand what should I wrap here by `Connect()` because I didn't use `AccountInfo` here:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import * as actions from '../../actions';

function setup() {
  const props = {
    errorMessage: null,
    actions
  };

  const enzymeWrapper = mount(<App {...props} />);

  return {
    props,
    enzymeWrapper,
  };
}

describe('App component', () => {
  it('shows account info and debits and credits`', () => {
    const {enzymeWrapper} = setup();
    expect(enzymeWrapper.find('.account-info').exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(enzymeWrapper.find('.debits-and-credits').exists()).toBe(true);
  });

  it('shows error message', () => {
    const {enzymeWrapper} = setup();
    enzymeWrapper.setProps({ errorMessage: 'Service Unavailable' });
    expect(enzymeWrapper.find('.error-message').exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

My `containers/app.js`:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';
import AppComponent from '../components/App/App';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isFetching: state.balance.isFetching,
  errorMessage: state.errorMessage,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch),
});

const AppContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppComponent);

export default AppContainer;
```

The component `app.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ErrorMessage from '../../containers/ErrorMessage';
import AccountInfo from '../../containers/AccountInfo';
import DebitsAndCredits from '../../containers/DebitsAndCredits';
import './App.css';

const AppComponent = () =>
  <div className="app">
    <AccountInfo />
    <DebitsAndCredits />
  </div>;

export class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const { actions } = this.props;
    actions.fetchBalance();
  }

  render() {
    const { errorMessage } = this.props;
    return errorMessage ? <ErrorMessage /> : <AppComponent />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

**UPD:**

I updated my test case and now it looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import { initialState } from '../../reducers/balance/balance';
import App from './App';
import * as actions from '../../actions';

const middlewares = [createSagaMiddleware];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);
const store = mockStore(initialState);

function setup() {
  const props = {
    errorMessage: null,
    actions,
  };

  const enzymeWrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App {...props} />
    </Provider>
  );

  return {
    props,
    enzymeWrapper,
  };
}

describe('App component', () => {
  it('shows account info and debits and credits`', () => {
    const { enzymeWrapper } = setup();
    expect(enzymeWrapper.find('.account-info').exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(enzymeWrapper.find('.debits-and-credits').exists()).toBe(true);
  });

  it('shows error message', () => {
    const { enzymeWrapper } = setup();
    enzymeWrapper.setProps({ errorMessage: 'Service Unavailable' });
    expect(enzymeWrapper.find('.error-message').exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

And my error now is:

```
App component › shows account info and debits and credits`

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'account' of undefined
```

**UPD 2:**

My `initialState` which I put when I create mocked store:

```
const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  account: {},
  currency: '',
  debitsAndCredits: [],
};
```

My `AccountInfo` component:

```
import React from 'react';

const AccountInfo = ({ account, currency }) =>
  <header className="account-info">
    <p>{account.name}</p>
    <p>
      IBAN: {account.iban}<br />
      Balance: {account.balance}<br />
      Currency: {currency}<br />
    </p>
  </header>;

export default AccountInfo;
```

Comment: I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49095870/3844548).

Answer (score 2):

For testing the connected component, you need to mock the provider as well, since the connect picks state variables from redux store.

Do this

```
const enzymeWrapper = mount (<Provider store={mockStore}><App {...props}/></Provider>)
```

You need to mock the redux store too.

Edit 1:

Just looking at your AccountInfo component it tells me that you are expecting account in the props here.

```
AccountInfo = ({account}) =>
```

So that means App.js has to pass down the accounts' value in the props. Same thing goes for currency.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I mocked store and maybe I did it using wrong way, can you take another one look at my post (i updated it), please.

Comment: Can you post what is your initial state that you are importing?

Comment: Also I need the code for AccountInfo container. I'm guessing that's where account is trying to be read.

Comment: On second thoughts, instead of posting it can you try to figure out which component is trying to look for "account" variable and make sure it's included in mocked store

Comment: Updated my post again. Thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: I want you to traverse your component hierarchy and figure out what all needs to be passed

Comment: Ok, but how to pass in my case the arguments for all children components. And I didn't pass any arguments in my component `app.js` so why I should pass them in the tests?

Comment: I mean I have no place to pass arguments for children components in my `app.js`.

Comment: Run this code normally also, I think it should throw the same error. If you can make a small fiddle and put relevant stuff there. I can make edits in that