# React Mocha-chai test not recognizing store from prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mocha.js, chai

I have a Mocha-chai test on a Redux connected React component. In order to pass the Redux store to the test component, I create it in the test file and pass it as a prop, but the test throws the following error:

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or
>   props of "Connect(Project)". Either wrap the root component in a
>   <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to
>   "Connect(Project)".

Here is the test:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { 
  renderIntoDocument,
  scryRenderedComponentsWithType
} from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import Project from '../../src/components/Project';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from '../../src/reducers/reducers';

const store = createStore(reducer);

const component = renderIntoDocument(
  <Project 
    store={ store } 
    project={
      {
        "name": "MyName",
        "img": "path.jpg",
        "img_alt": "alt desc",
        "description": "lorem ipsum",
        "github": "repository",
        "link": "website.com"
      }
    } />
);

describe('Project', () => {

  // tests ...

});
```

This is the React component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ProjectImage from './ProjectImage';
import ProjectText from './ProjectText';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions/actions';

export const Project = React.createClass({

  getProject: function() {
    return this.props.project || {};
  },

  handleClick: function(event) {
    this.props.dispatch(actions.showModal(true));
    this.props.dispatch(
      actions.setModalContent(this.getProject())
    );
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="project">

        <ProjectImage 
          img={ this.getProject().img } 
          imgAlt={ this.getProject().img_alt }
          link={ this.getProject().link } />

        <ProjectText 
          projectName={ this.getProject().name } 
          tagline={ this.getProject().tagline } 
          description={ this.getProject.description }
          github={ this.getProject().github }
          webLink={ this.getProject().link } 
          openModal={ this.handleClick } />

      </div>
    );
  }

});

export default connect()(Project);
```

Comment: can you try using `Provider` and passing it store.

Comment: `<Provider store = {store}><Project ...otherprops /></Provider>`

Comment: Yes, I did try adding the Provider and passing the store. Same error.

Comment: @mh why you are not using enzyme?

Comment: Are any of your tests passing? What line in the test file does the error happen on? You should be creating your stores and components using the `beforeEach()` hook inside your `describe` section.

Comment: I am not familiar with the `beforeEach()` hook. How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue you can do the following;

Install a library called redux-mock-store `npm install redux-mock-store`

Set up the store like this:

```
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';

const middlewares = [];
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
```

Add any middlewares you want included in the store, eg. redux-thunk, redux-sagas etc.

Define your initial state, and and create your store as follow:

```
initialState = {}
const store = mockStore(initialState);
```

Then connect your new store to the component you are testing:

```
const component = renderIntoDocument(
  <Project 
    store={ store } 
    project={
      {
        "name": "MyName",
        "img": "path.jpg",
        "img_alt": "alt desc",
        "description": "lorem ipsum",
        "github": "repository",
        "link": "website.com"
      }
    } />
);

describe('Project', () => {

  // tests ...

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you use `connect` for `Project` component without `mapStateToProps` or `mapDispatchToProps` functions?

However... It's not necessary to test wrapped component into `connect`. 
All you need is test plain `Project` component.

How to export both components? – Please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35578985/1349974) on the same issue.