# Can anyone provide an example on React-Redux Jest testing?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm having a really hard time learning how to use jest. All the tutorials i come across either teach you how to test a script that renders to dom such as `<App />` with or without snapshots. Other tutorials goes over how to mock tests with inputs. but I cant seem to find tutorials that explains clearly and give examples that i can use.

For example the script from below i have an idea on how to test the render portion, but i don't know how to test the redux or the rest of the functions.

Could anyone give an example of how to test the below script that i can use as a reference for the rest of the files i need to test in my project?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import CustomSearch from '../Components/CustomSearch';
import CustomToolBar from '../Components/CustomToolBar';
import Table from '../Components/Table';
import InsertButton from '../Components/InsertButton';

import UserForm from './UserForm ';

import { fetchUsers, deleteUser } from '../../actions/users';
import setModal from '../../actions/modal';

import TableColumns from '../../constants/data/TableColumns';

class Users extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onInsert = this.onInsert.bind(this);
    this.onDelete = this.onDelete.bind(this);
    this.onEdit = this.onEdit.bind(this);
    this.props.fetchUsers({ accountId: this.props.userData.account.id, token: props.userData.token });
  }

  onDelete(row) {
    if (confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete user ${row.first} ${row.last}?`)) {
      this.props.deleteUser({
        registered: row.registered,
        id: row.id,
        accountId: this.props.userData.account.id,
        token: this.props.userData.token
      });
    }
  }

  onEdit(row) {
    console.log(row);
    const modal = () => (<UserForm data={row} isEdit />);
    this.props.setCurrentModal(modal, 'Existing User Form');
  }

  onInsert() {
    const modal = () => (<UserForm />);
    this.props.setCurrentModal(modal, 'Add New User');
  }

  render() {
    const options = {
      searchField: (props) => (<CustomSearch {...props} />),
      insertBtn: () => (<InsertButton onClick={this.onInsert} />),
      toolBar: (props) => (<CustomToolBar {...props} />),
      onDelete: this.onDelete,
      onEdit: this.onEdit,
    };
    return (
      <Table data={this.props.users} columns={TableColumns.USERS} options={options} title="Users" />
    );
  }
}

User.propTypes = {
  setCurrentModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  fetchUsers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  deleteUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  userData: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  users: PropTypes.array,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  userData: state.userData.data,
  users: state.tableData.users,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  fetchUsers: (data) => dispatch(fetchUsers(data)),
  deleteUser: (data) => dispatch(deleteUser(data)),
  setCurrentModal: (modal, title) => dispatch(setModal(modal, title, null, true)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(User);
```

Comment: Seen as nobody has answers yet I will give you a full explanation when I am free tomorrow on how to do this. Do you know how to do testing in general and it's just the redux part where you connect components you are unsure of?

Comment: I have an idea on how to do snapshot testing and the basics thats about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should test raw component because it's clear that redux works so you don't have to test it. If for some reason you want to test `mapStateToProps` or `mapDispatchToProps` export them as well and test them separately in isolation.

So if you export your raw component like this:

```
export { Users }; // here you export raw component without connect(...)
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Users);
```

Then you can test it as a standard react component by importing named export, like

```
import { Users } from './Users';

describe('Users', () => ....
   it('should render', () => ...
```

If you would like to test `connected` component because you don't want `shallow` rendering and maybe you render a lot of nested connected components, you need to wrap your component with `<Provider>` and create a store for it.

You can help yourself by using [redux-mock-store](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html) that will apply middlewares for you.

Everything is very well explained in official redux documentation in [Recipes > Writing tests](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html), so my proposal is to read the whole chapter carefully. You can read there also about testing action creators, reducers and even more advanced concepts.

To read more and get better background, I encourage to check these 2 comments below from official redux / react-redux repos.

[image]

Direct link to comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/325#issuecomment-199449298

---

[image]

Direct link to comment: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1534#issuecomment-280929259

---

Related question on StackOverflow:

[How to Unit Test React-Redux Connected Components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131312/how-to-unit-test-react-redux-connected-components/35578985#35578985)

Comment: I've been writing tests for reducers and action creators and simple pure components such as button, container. I thought i had to test these bigger files where we have users and functions. Am i looking at jest wrong?

Comment: If you want to test methods `onEdit`, `onInsert`, `onDelete`, you can always get the instance of the component and test methods manually, like `const wrapper = mount(<Users />; const instance = wrapper.instance(); expect(instance.onDelete()).to...` etc. You can read more about enzyme `instance()` method here: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/v2.9.1/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.md

Comment: @hinok Don't use mount for unit testing components (which is almost certainly what OP wants to do). Use shallow and dive() instead.

Comment: @MartinDawson Agreed, but there are cases when you want mount a component e.g. testing logic in lifecycle hooks. I know that you can fire lifecycle hooks using shallow() but it's not very well documented in docs. PS. Back to my previous comment, why I put mount instead of shallow? The answer is - I just copied code from the enzyme's instance() docs :) https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/v2.9.1/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.md

Comment: @hinok You can use `lifecycleExperimental` to test lifecycle hooks as an option for shallow renderer. You don't need `mount` to test lifecycle anymore. You only should use mount for integration testing now.