# Material UI React Test cases failing - JEST, ENZYME

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, material-ui

I have a connected component and have integrated MaterialUI in my component. For some reason, the tests keep on failing and I am not able to find some article online to resolve this.

Please advice.

Below is my code.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import SourceCurrencyInput from './components/SourceCurrencyInput';
import TargetCurrencyInput from './components/TargetCurrencyInput';
import {fetchCurrencyConverterRates} from './actions/currencyConverterActions';
import CurrencyConverterValue from './components/CurrencyConverterValue';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import {withStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import './App.css';
import {
  changeSourceCurrencyValue,
  changeTargetCurrencyValue
} from './actions/actions';

const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  grow: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: -12,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
};

class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchCurrencyConverterRates(
      this.props.srcCurrencyType,
      this.props.tgtCurrencyType
    );
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if (prevProps.srcCurrencyType !== this.props.srcCurrencyType
      || prevProps.tgtCurrencyType !== this.props.tgtCurrencyType) {
      this.props.fetchCurrencyConverterRates(
        this.props.srcCurrencyType,
        this.props.tgtCurrencyType);
    }
  }

  clearAll = () => {
    this.props.sourceValue('');
    this.props.targetValue('');
  };

  render() {
    const {srcCurrencyType, tgtCurrencyType, srcCurrencyValue, tgtCurrencyValue, currencyConversionRate, classes} = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" className={classes.grow}>
              Currency Converter by Arun Manohar
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <header className="App-header">
          <SourceCurrencyInput/>
          <TargetCurrencyInput/>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button}
            onClick={() => this.clearAll()}>Clear</Button>
        </header>
        <CurrencyConverterValue srcCurrencyType={srcCurrencyType}
          tgtCurrencyType={tgtCurrencyType}
          srcCurrencyValue={srcCurrencyValue}
          tgtCurrencyValue={tgtCurrencyValue}
          currencyConversionRate={currencyConversionRate}
        />
        <footer><a href={'https://currencyconverterapi.com'} target={'_blank'}>API from currencyconverterapi.com</a></footer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    srcCurrencyType: state.currencyConverterReducer.sourceCurrencyType,
    tgtCurrencyType: state.currencyConverterReducer.targetCurrencyType,
    srcCurrencyValue: state.currencyConverterReducer.sourceCurrencyValue,
    tgtCurrencyValue: state.currencyConverterReducer.targetCurrencyValue,
    currencyConversionRate: state.getConvertedRates.data[0]
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  fetchCurrencyConverterRates: (src, tgt) => dispatch(fetchCurrencyConverterRates(src, tgt)),
  sourceValue: (val) => dispatch(changeSourceCurrencyValue(val)),
  targetValue: (val) => dispatch(changeTargetCurrencyValue(val)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withStyles(styles)(App));
```

Below is my test case.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import App from './App';
import {createMount} from '@material-ui/core/test-utils';

const mockStore = configureStore();
const initialState = {sourceCurrencyType: 'USD'};
const store = mockStore(initialState);

describe('<App />', () => {
  let mount;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mount = createMount();
  });

  it('should work', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><App/></Provider>);
    console.log(wrapper.debug());
  });
});
```

This is the error I get.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sourceCurrencyType' of undefined
```

I just need a way to access this component in my tests. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial state must keep the same structure with the reducer object, such:

```
const initialState = {
  currencyConverterReducer: {
    sourceCurrencyType: 'USD',
    // rest of attributes of currencyConverterReducer
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I can access the component. The className is am trying to find is deeply nested. Will mount work?

Comment: You better use `createShallow()` if you just want to unit test your component without having to care about its children.

Comment: I used createShallow now. wrapper.debug() returns me <ContextProvider value={{...}}>
        <Connect(WithStyles(App)) />
      </ContextProvider>. Any idea on how to access the App component?

Comment: Simplest _dirtiest_ solution would be to export also the class `App` definition and import it in your tests.

Comment: Any other way mate?

Comment: There are plenty of other SO questions addressing that issue. You can get more information, for example, in this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131312/how-to-unit-test-react-redux-connected-components

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189337/discussion-between-dez-and-a2441918).